# How can I define a optimizer as an attribute of a pytorch class?

Tags: python, pytorch

I created a deep learning model in Pytorch as below, it gives the error that which optimizer is not defined in PneumoniaModel class.

AttributeError: 'PneumoniaModel' object has no attribute 'optimizer'

```
class PneumoniaModel(pl.LightningModule):
  def _init_(self):
      self.model = torchvision.models.resnet18()
      self.model.conv1 = torch.nn.conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size = (7,7), stride = (2,2), padding =(3,3),      bias=False)
      self.model.fc = torch.nn.Linear(in_features = 512, out_features = 1, bias = True)

      self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr = 1e-4)
      self.loss_fn = torch.nn.BCEWithlogitsLoss(pos_weight = torch.tensor([3]))

      self.train_acc = torchmetrics.Accuracy()
      self.val_acc = torchmetrics.Accuracy()

  def forward(self, data):
      pred = self.model(data)
      return pred

  def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
      x_ray, label = batch
      label = label.float()
      pred = self(x_ray)[:,0]
      loss = self.loss_fn(pred, label)

      self.log("Train_Loss", loss)
      self.log("Step Train ACC :", self.train_acc(torch.sigmoid(pred), label.int()))

      return loss

  def on_train_epoch_end(self):
      epoch_average = torch.stack(self.training_step_outputs).mean()
      self.log("training_epoch_average", epoch_average)
      self.training_step_outputs.clear()  # free memory

 def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
      x_ray, label = batch
      label = label.float()
      pred = self(x_ray)[:,0]
      loss = self.loss_fn(pred, label)

      self.log("Val Loss", loss)
      self.log("Step Val ACC :", self.val_acc(torch.sigmoid(pred), label.int()))

 def on_validation_epoch_end(self):
      epoch_average = torch.stack(self.validation_step_outputs).mean()
      self.log("validation_epoch_average", epoch_average)
      self.validation_step_outputs.clear()  # free memory


 def configure_optimizers(self):   
     return [self.optimizer]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is literally as it is said. Pytorch Lightning improves the model definition through automation and compaction of several modules, including training functions and solvers (scheduler, optimizer, etc.). Therefore, it differs from conventional Pytorch scripts. All you need to do is define the model optimizer inside your model class.

Adding the code below inside your model will solve your issue.

```
def configure_optimizers(self):
    return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=1e-4)
```

If you wish, you can freely add or modify your optimizer, learning rate, and schedulers.

Comment: Thank you. I changed as you said and now it gives this error:     ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list

Comment: There is something wrong with your model definition. Your conv1 and fc should not be defined as such. If you want to add convolutional layer and fully connected layer sequentially after Resnet, use nn.Sequential().

Comment: @won5830 What if someone wants to use the optimizer as hyperparameter (i.e. play with different optimizers)? Should he pass the optimizer class in the `__init__` method of `LightningModule`? Is there a cleaner approach?